# How to move the entered data from one html file to its ts file and then to another component file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I generated two components login and home-page.I am trying to take user input from login template to login component and then to home-page template via home-page component. How do i do ?

I haven't write any code in any component file just in login template file.
Following is the login template code.

```js
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input   name="username" ngModel #name="ngModel" required minlength="4" maxlength="10" appForbiddenName="jedii" type="text">
   <div *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">username is mandatory</div>
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">username must be of min 4 characters</div>
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">username cannot be jedii</div>
   </div> 
  <br><br>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel">
</form>
<br>
 <button routerLink="/home">Login</button> 
<br>
<br>
<button (click)="loginForm.resetForm()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various possible ways to access user input data from html in ts file and pass data from one component to other.

**To access data in ts from template file, you can use two different types of forms:**

1. Template Driven ([Click here for more details](http://192.168.0.152:1234/#/campaign))
2. Reactive forms ([Click here for more details](http://192.168.0.152:1234/#/campaign))

**To pass data from one component to other, possible methods are:**([Click here for more details](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction))

1. Pass data from parent to child with input binding
2. Intercept input property changes with a setter
3. Intercept input property changes with ngOnChanges()
4. Parent listens for child event
5. Parent interacts with child via local variable
6. Parent calls an @ViewChild()
7. Parent and children communicate via a service

**In your case, I think best solution is to use Template driven forms and communication via service.** Rest depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction . You should check angular documentation before posting here. You can find everything about communication between components there. Cheers.